# Is there way to create a sync icon button that will spin when it press with react native-expo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

Is there a way to create a sync icon button that will spin when it pressed with react native-expo? 
I try to create a spinning icon of "sync" and I want it will show spinning animation the icon when pressed.

Answer (score -1):

Dont know what would be different in react-native but rotation is simply possible with css;
Add a class to your icon button and add an animation property to it.

```
.className{
      animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
      -webkit-animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
    }

@keyframes rotation {
    from {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
    }
  }
```

Here is an example I created in codeSandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-snow-773kp

Comment: I have added the example in my answer above. hope it will be useful.